# Symfony2 and Doctrine: how to fetch two different object for the same id?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have this scenario:

- Object A have some reference to other objects B,C,D
- Object B have some reference to other objects A,F,G
- Object C have some reference to other objects A,...

And so on.

In my code, I need to make a "copy" of an object (say A) for tmp reasons (no, I can't use a different structure, I need to have a copy of object).

If I use `clone`, obviously, I make a clone of my object but object related to him, aren't cloned.
I perfeclty know that I can override magic-method `__clone()` in order to assign to - from A object point of view - B,C,D as clone of objects themselves, but I have so many objects (and many of them are contained into `ArrayCollection` for Doctrine purpose) and I would prefer to avoid the override of each object's clone function.

Alternatively, I thought that I can refetch an object from doctrine to make a new one, in that way:

```
$aCopy = $this->entity_manager
                       ->getRepository('MyBundle:A')
                       ->find($a->getId());
```

where `$a` is an instance of `class A`

After doing this operation - *that of course is "wrong" because I suspect that doctrine will mark that object as "alredy fetched" and return its pointer(*)* - I simply print the ID of my two objects with `spl_object_hash()` function and, of course again, they refer to the same object ID, so to the same object.

#### PS.:

I can't use doctrine `detach()` function because i need to have the original object available after this operation

## Question

How can I tackle this situation? As you can see, I've tryied two different ways and no one of them had satisfied me.

### Note

I've tagged php also, because if someone could point me to a different solution, php-pure based, I'll take it into account also

(*)

> In this case the Article is accessed from the entity manager twice,
> but modified in between. Doctrine 2 realizes this and will only ever
> give you access to one instance of the Article with ID 1234, no matter
> how often do you retrieve it from the EntityManager and even no matter
> what kind of Query method you are using (find, Repository Finder or
> DQL). This is called “Identity Map” pattern, which means Doctrine
> keeps a map of each entity and ids that have been retrieved per PHP
> request and keeps returning you the same instances.

That confirm what I've said previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was less complex than I expected.

It seem to be sufficent call `$this->entity_manager->clear();` that will clear this entity map and force it to reload from database into a brand new object!

```
$this->entity_manager->clear();
$aCopy = $this->entity_manager
                       ->getRepository('MyBundle:A')
                       ->find($a->getId());
            $this->logger->debug('Original Obj: '.spl_object_hash($a));
            $this->logger->debug('Copied Obj:      '.spl_object_hash($aCopy));
```

this will print

> [2013-02-08 12:07:20] app.DEBUG: Original Obj:
>   000000006523**645c**000000004b1160d1 [] [] [2013-02-08 12:07:20]
>   app.DEBUG: Copied Obj:   000000006523**66e3**000000004b1160d1 [] []

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know this is not a supported D2 behaviour out of the box, so I would say you'll need to implement the clone operation yourself.

Having said that, I'm also not 100% sure what'll happen if you serialize and then unserialize a D2 entity, this might do what you want (albeit in a rather unpleasant fashion). In addition you *could*, after fetching the entity initially, detach what you've received immediately and re-fetch the result again before any references to the 'live' copy have propagated outside of the original instantiation point (if the query's using the result cache this shouldn't carry too much of a penalty). Presumably this wouldn't be a tremendous problem however, as you're just working with the copy temporarily.

WRT to clearing the entity manager, it'll detach *all* managed entities, which may well have undesirable side-effects.

HTH.

Comment: I've found an alternative solution. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @DonCallisto Final sentence of mine pays respects to it there yeah, in that it has the potential to detach objects outside of those directly intended. But ofc in the right circumstance, that'll indeed work.

Comment: I don't think that he'll detach (they're object and they hare related with pointers) but, in the worst case, he have to do (again) some query for retrive some objects that were not involved in "copy" scenario